Unlocking from lockscreen causes the super key to lose all functionality
Super key malfunctions when unlocked from lock screen
This bug affects every second unlock of my computer.
After unlocking, instead of showing the dock, the "Show Apps" icon persist (regardless of whether auto-hide dock is turned on).
In other words, it looks like this:

Instead of this:

At this point, when I try to use any shortcut key involving the super key (e.g. super+1, super+2 etc.), it fails to start any program.

notify-send would not work: there are no notifications generated.
super+num_key would not work: there are no indication when these buttons are pressed.
alt+tab and alt+` would not work: there are no indication when these buttons are pressed.
Pressing super traps me into the following purgatory: If I try to press the super key, it opens the Activities Overview page as usual, but inside the page is just a blank screen (greyed out where the desktop would've been). If I try to press the super key again, it opens the Application Overview as usual, but again, the desktops/workspaces are blank, even though the apps are displayed. No matter how many times I try to press esc after this point, I stay trapped on these two pages.

Steps to reproduce
On Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, In the login screen cog wheel, choose "Ubuntu"/"Ubuntu On Wayland".
After login, press super+L to lock the screen. Enter password to unlock once.
After the first unlock, press super+L to lock again, and then enter password. This time, the weird behaviour will show up.
Workaround
In the login screen cog wheel, choose "GNOME"/"GNOME classic Wayland" as the display manager. I think these might be older versions of the display manager.

did you consider this page in the context of the version you have in use from your upgrade to 24.04 and have you reported the issue to the developer by email to micxgx@gmail.com

@graham thanks, yes, I've just done that.

I found out the reason for this weird behaviour afterwards, which does not require changing to Ubuntu/Wayland.
Before upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04.1, I had this application installed called the "Dash to Dock".

After the upgrade to 24.04, its functionality of keeping the dash visible is replaced by the org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide in gsettings. The extension therefore interfered with how the dock is displayed.
Solution
Disable/ uninstall the Dash to Dock gnome extension.
